# Measure sideways tilt of upright device

Tags: android, physics, accelerometer, android-sensors, screen-rotation

Some camera apps have a feature where they display a line on the screen which is always parallell to the horizon, no matter how the phone is tilted sideways. By "tilted sideways" I mean rotating the device around an axis that is perpendicular to the screen.

I have tried most of the "normal" rotation functions such as combining the `ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor with `getRotationMatrix()` and `getOrientation()` but none of the resulting axis seem to correspond to the one I'm looking for.

I also tried using only the accelerometer, normalizing all three axis and detecting how much gravity is in the `X-axis`. This works decently when the device is perfectly upright (i.e not tilted forward/backwards). But as soon as it's tilted forward or backward the measured sideways tilt gets increasingly inaccurate, since gravity is now acting on two axis at the same time.

Any ideas on how to achieve this kind of sideways rotation detection in a way that works even if the phone is tilted/pitched slightly forward/backward?

Answer (score 1):

The result of `getRotationMatrix` converts from the phone's local coordinate system to the world coordinate system. Its columns are therefore the *principal axes* of the phone, with the first being the phone's `X`-axis (the +ve horizontal axis when holding the phone in portrait mode), and the second being the `Y`.

To obtain the horizon's direction on the phone's screen, the line of intersection between the horizontal plane (world space) and the phone's plane must be found. First find the coordinates of the world `Z`-axis (pointing to the sky) in the phone's local basis - i.e. `transpose(R) * [0, 0, 1]`; the `XY` coordinates of this, given by `R[2][0], R[2][1]`, is the *vertical* direction in screen-space. The required horizon line direction is then **`R[2][1], -R[2][0]`**.

When the phone is close to being horizontal, this vector becomes very small in magnitude - the horizon is no-longer well-defined. Simply stop updating the horizon line below some threshold.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure exactly how I would implement your `transpose(R) * [0, 0, 1`? Since this is StackOverflow and not Math StackExchange it'd be helpful to include some code.

Comment: @badcash you don't need to. You only need the end result which is `R[2][1], -R[2][0]`. And anyways I don't see how hard it would be to implement, no offence